# Why is multiprocessing performance is invisible?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I saw the reference [here](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/), and tried to use the method for my for loop, but it seems not working as expected.

```
def concatMessage(obj_grab, content):
    for logCatcher in obj_grab:
        for key in logCatcher.dic_map:
            regex = re.compile(key)
            for j in range(len(content)):
                for m in re.finditer(regex, content[j]):
                    content[j] += "           " + logCatcher.index + "        " + logCatcher.dic_map[key]
    return content

def transferConcat(args):
    return concatMessage(*args)

if __name__ == "__name__":
    pool = Pool()
    content = pool.map(transferConcat, [(obj_grab, content)])[0]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I want to enhance the performance of for loop because it takes 22 seconds to run.

When I run the method directly, it also takes about 22 seconds.

It seems the enhancement has failed.

What should I do to enhance my for loop speed? 
Why is `pool.map` not working in my case?

---

After remind by nablahero, I revised my code as below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    content = input_file(target).split("\n")
    content = manager.list(content)
    for files in source:
        obj_grab.append((LogCatcher(files), content))
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(transferConcat, obj_grab)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def concatMessage(LogCatcher, content):
    for key in LogCatcher.dic_map:
        regex = re.compile(key)
        for j in range(len(content)):
            for m in re.finditer(regex, content[j]):
                content[j] += LogCatcher.index + LogCatcher.dic_map[key]

def transferConcat(args):
    return concatMessage(*args)
```

after the long waiting, it caused 82 secs to finish...

Why I got this situation? How can I revise my code?

---

obj_grab is a list, which contains logCatchers of different file intput
content is the file I want to concat, and use Manager() to let multiprocess concat the same file.

Comment: What do you mean "performance is invisible"? What kind of performance is  visible?

Comment: unrelated but you can iterate over content instead  of indexing

Comment: This example code will be *slower* than the equivalent sequential code. All you're doing is running a single function in a child process, and waiting for it to complete. The cost of IPC to send the function and its arguments to the child process will make it slower than if you just ran it all in the parent. `Pool.map` is only useful when you use it to run many functions in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

What's in obj_grab and content? I guess it only contains one object so when you're starting your Pool you call the function transferConcat only once because you only got one object in obj_grab and content.

If you use map have a look at your reference again. obj_grab and content must be lists of objects in order to speed your program up, because it call the function multiple times with different obj_grab and content's.

pool.map does not speed up the function itself - the function just gets called multiple times in parallel with different data!

I hope that clears some things up.